# AngularJS, how do I make a button print something?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, printing

I have a table and then above it I added a print button, what could I put in the ng-click to make the browser print my page following the print css I set up?

I have a page.htm and a controller.ts, if you could explain me how to do it, I would love that when you press on the printer button, a preview comes out and from there you can confirm the printing!

I tried using something found here:

```
$scope.printDiv = function(divName) {
  var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
  var popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'width=300,height=300');
  popupWin.document.open();
  popupWin.document.write('<html><head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" /></head><body onload="window.print()">' + printContents + '</body></html>');
  popupWin.document.close();
}
```

but if I put it in the controller it gives me errors, first for the $scope (cannot find name $scope) and second for function (divName) (parameter "divName" implicitly has an ''any'' type).

I'm new with AngularJS so I'm a bit lost, especially on where the code goes!

thank you

Comment: Why not use `window.print()`

Comment: looks at @media queries you can manage directly your print view of your page : https://benfrain.com/create-print-styles-using-css3-media-queries/

Answer (score 0):

You can use ngPrint directive for printing 
      https://github.com/gilf/ngPrint